# Masking all but first character in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm afraid my solution is not very efficient:

```kotlin
fun String.mask() = if (isEmpty()) {
    this
} else {
    this[0] + String((1 until length).map { '*' }.toCharArray())
}
```

How would you do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use [`replaceRange`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace-range.html) to do the replacing, and [`repeat`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/repeat.html) to construct the repeated asterisks:

```
fun String.mask() =
    if (isEmpty())
        ""
    else
        replaceRange(1, length, "*".repeat(length - 1))
```

Comment: I got curious, if you do this the other way around ``"*".repeat(length).replaceFirstChar { first() }`` it's about twice as fast (by my extremely lazy benchmarking). The ``CharArray`` approach is about 50% slower. If someone out there needs to obfuscate a billion passwords, this will be useful info!

Answer (score 1):

You can just init an array full of `*` and set the first character too:

```
fun String.mask() = if (isEmpty()) {
    this
} else {
    CharArray(length) { '*' }.also { it[0] = this[0] }.joinToString(separator = "")
}
```

actually since the init block for the array is a function, we can just do

```
CharArray(length) { i -> if (i == 0) this[0] else '*' }.joinToString("")
```

and you can use `first()` instead of `this[0]` if that's more readable

Comment: I find @Sweeper's answer more readable

Comment: @jjrz well you did say efficient, not readable ;) not that this is more efficient than Sweeper's, I checked!